# Identifying an IC, LNK364PN

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, switching-regulator

The other night the corner of a switcher IC in a LED lamp power adapter blew off.

I opened the adapter and "reassembled" the IC case with tweezers to identify the model.

[image]

I see it's a LNK364PN and I found the [datasheet](https://www.power.com/sites/default/files/product-docs/lnk362-364.pdf).

Can I ignore the first and the third line of numbers printed on the IC (0948 and 68089E respectively)?

Comment: Yes, you can. These are typically date codes or other, manufacturer-specific information. E.g. 0948 is likely shorthand for "made in 2009, week 48".

Comment: Thanks. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: If you’re trying to fix it, don’t ignore the fuse, which is probably blown too.

Comment: Indeed, I will try to repair it. Thought of the fuse, too. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore the other 2 lines.

These are typically date codes or other, manufacturer-specific information. E.g. 0948 is likely shorthand for "made in 2009, week 48". Sometimes information about how to decode the marking on the case is included in the datasheet, but in this case it isn't